# Angular 2 - Sanitize Router Link

Tags: angular, sanitize

I'd like to return to my HTML page custom router links.

In my HTML I have:

```
<span [innerHTML]="value | toRouterLink"></span>
```

the toRouterLink pipe returns a sanitized router link:

```
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<a routerLink="/item/something">${value}</a>`);
```

When I click on it, nothing happens, as if there's no directive at all.

If however I swap "routerLink" with "href", clicking the link works (although naturally it leads to nowhere).

How do I make the routerLink work after sanitization?

It seems that any directive doesn't work, e.g. (click)="myFunc()" doesn't call myFunc().

From what I understood from other topics on the subject the sanitization process should register directives and anything else related to the angular environment, but for some reason it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead try

```js
return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustURL("/item/something");
```

```html
<span>
  <a [routerLink]="value | toRouterLink">${value}</a>
</span>
```

Comment: The pipe actually returns more than just router links, it returns all kinds of html with attached angular directives, so I can't really do that, I need to be able to properly sanitize HTML.

Comment: @RoyiBernthal have you found the solution for the issue?

Comment: Not directly, I created a workaround that worked for my specific issue - I created a component that "translates" some types for me instead of a pipe, so that routerLink is already in the HTML template and doesn't need sanitizing. I use ngSwitch to choose between different cases to display, e.g. string, number, boolean.